# remove products from cart where price is 0

Tags: magento

Is it possible to remove products from cart in Magento when product's price is 0?

Maybe its possible to update quantity of the product and set to 0?

I would like to remove free products whic are gifts, problem is there are also bundle product with the same id as free product so if I remove product by id it will destroy bundlne also

Comment: "as in topic remove products", What do u mean by this?? IN which topid they said?? Please brief your question.. Or else you will be getting minus points to your question.. They have already started coming for your question...

Comment: I don't have idea how to do it, that is why I'm asking

Comment: What you need to do it?? First say on it

Comment: I would like to remove free products whic are gifts, problem is there are also bundle product with the same id as free product so if I remove product by id it will destroy bundlne also

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it.But you can.  It is not understood from your question when and from where you should put the below code

```
<?php 
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item)
{

    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    if($productPrice==0){
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save(); I cant remove product by id, because in this case it will be also removed form bundle